# PHP output is empty

Tags: php, output

this is my code php5.6

```
$lang = array(
  "HTML" => "60%",
  "CSS" => "80%",
  "JS" => "70%",
  "PHP" => "50%",
);

echo "<ul>";

for ($lang=0; $lang < count($lang) ; $lang++) {
  echo "<li>" . $lang[$lang] . "</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
```

When i run my page it does't show any thing

Comment: You're overwriting your array with `0`. `for ($lang=0;` Use a different iterator name like `$x` or `$i`

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach on arrays.

```
$langs = array(
  'HTML'=> '60%',
  'CSS' => '80%',
  'JS'  => '70%',
  'PHP' => '50%',
);

echo '<ul>';

foreach ($langs as $lang=>$per) {
  echo "<li>$lang $per</li>";
}

echo '</ul>';
```